# Google Doc Api for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios

I have found many links for iPhone project which is implementing the google API but not a single one is in running condition has anyone know the link of any tutorial which can successfully download or upload file from google documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Google Docs API [over here](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/)

The first two sections on that page provide further links to how you can both [retrieve](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#SearchingDocs) and [export](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDocs) documents using the API.

You can use any number of third-party libraries such as [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking) to access the API over HTTP, or roll your own using [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: NSString *authorizationHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin auth=\"%@\"" , [another objectAtIndex:1]];    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full"];    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url2];

Comment: [urlRequest2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    [urlRequest2 setValue:@"2.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];    [urlRequest2 setValue:authorizationHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];[urlRequest2 setValue:Length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    [urlRequest2 setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];    [urlRequest2 setValue:slugStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"Slug"];    [urlRequest2 setHTTPBody:audioData];

Comment: Above is the code for my HTTP request.The response i get is invalid token @micpringle

Comment: What does `[another objectAtIndex:1]` contain? The docs suggest using OAuth 2.0 to authorise a user and obtain an authorisation token; are you doing this?

Comment: it's the authorization token google returned using client login.

Comment: The authorisation header should look like this `Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=theToken` ... yours seems to have some extra backslashes in which aren't required.

Comment: GoogleLogin Auth=DQAAALwAAABr-yEKe01WT4DsIBRcBi2_RMEU2oRKJDU1DJ2A9_YfhYZf1lXmVs5b_9bVqGashnSSS1ljIGi4XWd3l9DO8TLT4w24qDeKxS342bprl0Nyn5cFrdNdSfF3-YzudqIMYC1Xkf-b2VjARp-fWYU3Qhta6QN4tXaRHkFGnf1BEzGVrQVJd3EE987RWmC3qFy52X5lbybRmXPGRsJJ6msH6WhRZkg5UrN9S5jPrMtVQfJlpAv4slExwsMo6TTDZEfZXVc

Comment: this is what i'm sending to the authorization header. This long string is the actual token returned by google.

Comment: I can't help beyond that then I'm afraid.

Comment: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML> this is the response which i am getting any way Micpringle thank you for your co-operation and giving response to my questions

Comment: can i send u the code of my project. I will going be very thank full to you because i am working on this project scene 12-14 day but unable to solve this problem :(

Comment: I suggest you ask another question here on SO specific to the error you're seeing. **Make sure** to include as much information as you can, and post all the relevant code.